# No Visible Interface when calling method

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics

Calling method as follows, however I am getting no visible Interface error!

[image]

```
// My Header
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SectionViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imvPhoto;
+(UIImage*) drawImage:(UIImage*) fgImage
              inImage:(UIImage*) bgImage
              atPoint:(CGPoint)  point;

@end

// Implementation
+(UIImage*) drawImage:(UIImage*) fgImage
              inImage:(UIImage*) bgImage
              atPoint:(CGPoint)  point
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bgImage.size, FALSE, 0.0);
    [bgImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, bgImage.size.width, bgImage.size.height)];
    [fgImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, fgImage.size.width, fgImage.size.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Problem has fixed with changing

from

```
+(UIImage*) drawImage:(UIImage*) fgImage
              inImage:(UIImage*) bgImage
              atPoint:(CGPoint)  point
```

to

```
-(UIImage*) drawImage:(UIImage*) fgImage
              inImage:(UIImage*) bgImage
              atPoint:(CGPoint)  point
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. You are missing [ and ].

Use:

```
imvPhoto.image = [YourClassName drawImage:imvPhoto.image inImage:anno.image atPoint:point];
```

Instead of:

```
imvPhoto.image = drawImage:imvPhoto.image inImage:anno.image atPoint:point;
```

Comment: @casillas: Check the answer, if you are calling the method from the class itself use self

Comment: again, updated and different error message. I have exactly copied your code.